# What is the default value of a session variable?

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
else
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;

echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views']; 
?>
```

Is `$_SESSION['views']` initialized as `FALSE`?

EDIT: I meant the third line of code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question... in this case, `$_SESSION['views']` is initialized with the value `1`, as indicated by your `else` statement.

Comment: The "default" value of any variable is undefined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's like this: if the user has never been to your site, then you are starting a new session and `$_SESSION['views']` will not be set (so you set it to 1). On the other hand if the user's request comes with a session ID of a valid session, then the variable will be set to whatever it was last stored as.

Comment: That's correct.  So the first time someone is on the site, what is $_SESSION['views'] equal to?

Comment: It's just not set, like any variable you've not referred to before. That's why you use `isset`.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing special with `$_SESSION['views']`. `$_SESSION` is a "normal" array. If you don't set anything, `views` is just an undefined array index.

Answer (score 3):

It's initialised as `1`, because you told it to be.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['views']` is initialized as whatever you set it as. According to your example, it would be initialized as `1` or `TRUE`.